# Data series in Layout and Format not matching?

Tags: microsoft-excel, colors, charts, format, layout

I have a bit of a peculiar situation - I am trying to color multiple data series based off of slicer selections a different color. When all the data series (or multiple data series) are on the graph they appear in their assigned colors.

However whenever I select for a specific data series it is always in the last color I selected - It is almost as if the color selection is applying to all rather than the specific data series.

I tried to figure it out and see that when I select a data series the layout changes to the correct data series, but the format selection retained is a different data series?

What seems to be happening?

- Thanks puts for the forum choice